# drop new object in draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I append value of `data-mine` ? (after drop)

[**THE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Eagle_Design/xnj9ku6b/)

here is my trye

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    var transferred = false;
    $('#draggable li').draggable({
        connectToSortable: '#sortable',
        helper: 'clone',
    });

    $('#sortable').sortable();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="draggable">
    <li data-mine='hi'>Hello</li>
    <li data-mine='why'>Stack</li>
    <li data-mine='flow'>Overflow</li>
</ul>


<ul id="sortable"></ul>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using jQuery UI? You need it for `.draggable()`.

Comment: Sorry about my wrong answer before. Anyway, I'm going to make another correct answer that answers your question. One second...

Comment: Sorry, I'm still working on it! Almost done, though.

Comment: thanks i think your not here :( :X :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87658/discussion-between-danial-dezfooli-and-noble-mushtak).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use jQuery UI for `.draggable()` to work because regular jQuery doesn't have `.draggable()`. Just make sure you include that and everything should work fine.

Also, to get the `data-mine` attribute in the original list, use `ui.item` in the `receive` event and then use `.attr()` and save it in a variable. Then, to append the `data-mine` attribute in the new list, use `ui.item` in the `stop` event and then use `.text()` with the previously mentioned variable.

```js
$(function() {
    var transferred = false;
    $('#draggable li').draggable({
        connectToSortable: '#sortable',
        helper: 'clone',
    });

    var sortable = $('#sortable');
    //This is the data-mine attribute of the last object dropped in:
    var curDataMine;
    sortable.sortable({
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            transferred = true;
            //Here, we append the data-mine attribute onto the item in the original list:
            curDataMine = ui.item.attr("data-mine");
        },
        stop: function(event, ui)
        {
            transferred = true;
            //Here, we append the data-item attribute onto the item in the sortable list:
            ui.item.text(curDataMine);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#draggable, #sortable {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 30px;
}

#draggable li, #sortable li {
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
#sortable {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul id="draggable">
    <li data-mine='hi'>Hello</li>
    <li data-mine='why'>Stack</li>
    <li data-mine='flow'>Overflow</li>
</ul>


<ul id="sortable"></ul>
```

Comment: i want to paste `data-mine` attribute